# Understanding the result of the decimal constructor with 5 arguments

Tags: c#

Can you tell me how this output come? i don't understand this logics behind the scenes.. :p

here is my code:

```
using System;

public class MainProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal d = new decimal(1234, 12121, 5454, false, 5);

        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1006085422300711931.09714
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using the decimal [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to specify different parts of the decimal value.  From the linked documentation:

> **lo** - The low 32 bits of a 96-bit integer.
>
> **mid** - The middle 32 bits of a 96-bit integer.
>
> **hi** - The high 32 bits of a 96-bit integer.
>
> **isNegative** - true to indicate a negative number; false to indicate a positive number.
>
> **scale** - A power of 10 ranging from 0 to 28.

Taking some simple examples, you can see how the different values affect the creation of the decimal value:

```
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(0, 0, 0, false, 0)); //0
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(1, 0, 0, false, 0)); //1
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(0, 1, 0, false, 0)); //4294967296
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(0, 0, 1, false, 0)); //18446744073709551616
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(1, 0, 0, false, 1)); //0.1
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(1, 0, 0, true, 1)); //-0.1
```

Comment: Your answer was good :)